# Dynamic Text of a Movie Clip is not updating

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a stage set up with a "movie clip" in the frame named `jackpotNote`. In that movie clip (or symbol), there is a dynamic text field named "jackpotAmt".

What is supposed to happen is that I'm to press the Space Bar on my keyboard and it will trigger the Movie Clip to play out. What's also supposed to happen is that the text is supposed to change as well, here is the current coding:

```
        if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {

            if (jackpotNote.visible == true) {
                trace("Jackpot amount already shown. Ignored.");
            } else {
                jackpotNote.visible = true;
                jackpotSymbol.visible = true;

                //jackpotSymbol.jackpotAmt.text =  currency_str + String(jackpotamt_int);
                if (jackpotamt_int < 100000) jackpotSymbol.jackpotAmt.text = currency_str + String(jackpotamt_int);
                else if (jackpotamt_int >= 100000 && jackpotamt_int <= 999999) jackpotSymbol.jackpotAmt.text = String(jackpotamt_int);
                else jackpotSymbol.jackpotAmt.text = currency_str + "1MIL+";

                dingsound.play();
                jackpotSymbol.play(); // DO NOT START PLAYING 
                jackpotSymbol.gotoAndPlay(1);

                trace("Jackpot amount shown.");

            }


        }
```

However when I trigger this event, the following happens:

- The sound effect `jackpotSymbol.play()` plays as normal.
- The `jackpotSymbol` becomes visible.
- However, the text is not changed in the following line: `jackpotSymbol.jackpotAmt.text = currency_str + String(jackpotamt_int);`

This used to run well on Adobe Flash Professional CS6, however when I upgrade to Adobe Animate CC... it broke. (I had to remove all of the TLF fields and make them dynamic again.)

What is missing to make all of this work?

Comment: Hi @PaulWilliams I remember having a problem like this years ago. Try embedding the text font.

Comment: @Moynul: Right now all of the fonts that I'm using are embedded but there is still no change.

Comment: try putting the dynamic text on a seperate layer, but ensure there is only one keyframe, other than that, I have never used Adobe Animate, only Adobe Flash 8-CS6. I would revert if you can.

Comment: Shy of restarting the construction of the movie, I'm refusing to believe that this isn't something that can be solved using the current program. The Flash Player and ActionScript settings are the same.

Comment: @Moynul: After doing some digging around, it turns out that this problem has to do with the fact that TLF fields aren't supported in CC... Therefore... this means I HAVE to rollback to CS6 and use TLF fields in the interval.